# Delta systems under Martin's Axiom

Tags: set-theory

The $\Delta$-system Lemma states that given an uncountable family $\mathcal C$ of sets with finite intersection there exist an uncountable subfamily $\mathcal D$ of $\mathcal C$ and a finite set $\Delta$ such that $d_1 \cap d_2=\Delta$, for all $d_1$ e $d_2$ distinct elements of $\mathcal D$. Does MA($\kappa$) imply that given a family $\mathcal C$ of $\kappa$ sets with finite intersection, there exist a subfamily $\mathcal D$ of $\mathcal C$ with $|\mathcal D|=\kappa$ and a finite set $\Delta$ such that $d_1 \cap d_2=\Delta$, for all $d_1$ e $d_2$ distinct elements of $\mathcal D$?

Answer (score 7):

Martin's Axiom plays no role here.

This generalization of the Delta System Lemma is true (in ZFC) if and only if  $\kappa$ is a regular uncountable cardinal. This is lemma III.2.6 and exercise III.2.7 in Kunen's book Set Theory (the last edition).

Edit: As Mike pointed out in his answer, there is a missing assumption: one must assume that the family consists of finite sets (both for the usual lemma and its generalization).

There are also generalizations for family of infinite sets. See for instance [the answer from Joel David Hamkins to this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/21409/the-delta-system-lemma-outside-set-theory?rq=1).

Answer (score 2):

Your formulation of delta-system lemma and attempted generalization (under MA) fail because there is an uncountable almost disjoint family of infinite subsets of $\omega$. You must assume that your family consists of finite sets and not just that their pairwise intersections are finite.

I am not sure what Charles' answer was intended to address.

Comment: Yes, I understood it some hours ago ;-)

Comment: Indeed, I overlooked the missing assumption. I will edit my answer. Thanks.